# How to call functions of imported modules automatically?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm generating the pictures of my latex document with the following program `genimg.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

def figCircle():
    print('generate circle picture')
def figSquare():
    print('generate square picture')

def main():
    for key, value in globals().items():
        if callable(value) and key.startswith('fig'):
            value()

if __name__== "__main__":
    main()
```

Now, since the images get more and more, I would like to split `genimg.py` in more files, lets say `genimgFirst.py` and `genimgSecond.py` and the `genimg.py` should go through the modules starting with `genimg` and execute all functions starting with `fig`. Lets assume that I add `import genimgFirst` and `import genimgSecond` at the beginning of my new modified `genimg.py`.

Is this possible (without a revolution, that is just copy and paste of my fig* functions)?

**EDIT**
Here the code after a merge of the two answers of @bluenote and @inspectorG4dget:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import glob

def main():
    for fname in glob.glob("genimg*.py"):  # get all the relevant files
        if fname == "genimg.py":
            continue
        print('>>>> {}'.format(fname))
        mod = fname.rsplit('.',1)[0]
        mod = __import__(mod)  # import the module
        for k,v in mod.__dict__.items():
            if callable(v) and k.startswith('fig'): v()  # if a module attribute is a function, call it

if __name__== "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could call your code recursively for imported modules. Something like

```
import types

def call_functions(module_dict):
   for key, value in module_dict.items():
        if callable(value) and key.startswith('fig'):
            value()
        elif isinstance(value, types.ModuleType):
            call_functions(value.__dict__)

if __name__=='__main__':
    call_functions(globals())
```

Comment: For newbie like me: add `import types`, then it works perfectly!

Comment: @AaronLenz: if you got up to that point, you don't seem too much of a newbie

Comment: I've to wait 3 mins. By the next upvote, I'll be able to upvote you also.

Comment: The code I use is copy and paste from somewhere here. I just generate .tex files...

Answer (score 2):

```
import glob

for fname in glob.glob("genimg*.py"):  # get all the relevant files
    mod = gname.rsplit('.',1)([0])
    mod = __import__(mod)  # import the module
    for k,v in mod.__dict__.items():
        if callable(v): v()  # if a module attribute is a function, call it
```